# How to reference a protocol's associatedtype

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I have some enums that conform to a protocol with an associated type:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func foo() -> T
}

enum MyEnum1: MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

enum MyEnum2: MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

I want to be able to "dynamically" create a dictionary that maps from one of my enums to an array of its associated types. Something like this:

```
struct MyStruct<T: MyProtocol> {
    var map = [T: [any T.associatedtype]]() // need to reference the associated type here
}
```

I'm aware that `T.associatedtype` isn't valid, just trying to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

This is a pretty slimmed down version of my code so I'm happy to provide more context if needed.

Comment: The protocol has _one_ associated type yet you talk about enums with arrays of associated types, this is confusing to say the least. Could you explain what you mean, maybe with an example?

Comment: I've realized I made a typo and left out some intentionally important info. The dict's declaration line should be `var map = [T: [ any T.associatedtype]]()`. And the enums' associated types aren't concrete types like String/Int, they're protocols. I'll update the question to better reflect this

Comment: You refer to the associated type by the name you give it.  In your example both the associated type and the generic parameter in the struct are named T, so you would refer to the associated type of the generic parameter as `T.T`

Comment: This isn't possible. You cannot have a Dictionary where the Value associated type has a different concrete type per-key. For the tool you're looking for, see SwiftUI Environment and EnvironmentKey. Also see AttributedContainer and also PreferenceKey. These are all very closely-related way to do what you're describing. You probably will need to build your own implementation; these are just several examples of how it's done. You can even use subscripts. But you can't use Dictionary this way.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier -- I'll look into those alternatives